# How to count combination results and place in seperate table using Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have table containing the following information:

| Host name | Test name | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Host_01 | Test-01 | **Pass** |
| Host_01 | Test-02 | **Fail** |
| Host_01 | Test-03 | **N/A** |
| Host_01 | Test-04 | **Pass** |
| Host_01 | Test-05 | **Pass** |
| Host_02 | Test-01 | **Pass** |
| Host_02 | Test-02 | **Fail** |
| Host_02 | Test-03 | **Fail** |
| Host_02 | Test-04 | **Pass** |

Now I want/need to transform this to the following result:

| Host name | Num_of_Tests_per_Host | Num_Passed | Num_Failed | Num_N/A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Host_01 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| Host_02 | 4 | 2 | 2 | null |

I created the queries to extract the disctinct host list and count the distinct "Test name -  Result" occurances. But I can't get my head around how to merge these queries to create the results table.

This will probably be an "Arggh ... Why didn't I think of that!!!" solution, but can't seem to catch it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are already counting the number of occurrences of each event per `Host name`, isn't that what you are showing for your results?  What is your problem?  And you forgot to include the code you are using.

Comment: I editted the table layout. Made an error there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let

//Change table name in next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table18"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Host name", type text}, 
        {"Test name", type text}, 
        {"Result", type text}}),

//Group by Host Name
//  Aggregate to get total of tests, Pass, Fail, N/A
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Host name"}, {
       {"Num_of_Tests_per_Host", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type},
       {"Num_Passed", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[Result], each _="Pass")), Int64.Type},
       {"Num_Failed", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[Result], each _="Fail")), Int64.Type},
       {"Num_N/A", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[Result], each _="N/A")), Int64.Type}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the cell contents are nulls instead of text saying null,

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Host name"},{
    {"Num_of_Tests_per_Host", each List.Count(List.Distinct([Test name])), type number},
    {"Num_Passed", each List.NonNullCount([Passed]), type number},
    {"Num_Failed", each List.NonNullCount([Failed]), type number},
    {"Num_N/A", each List.NonNullCount([#"N/A"]), type number}
})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```